# Combine Two Commands In a Script

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, scripts

I want to put two commands together

I need the script to login:

```
ssh root@192.168.0.188
```

Then I need to the script to run (while logged in to root@192.168.0.188 via ssh ):

```
find /var/mobile/Media/Music/ -name "*.mp3" -exec ln -s {} /var/mobile/Media/Music/"All Songs" \;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include a command to run on the remote machine as the last argument to ssh

```
ssh root@192.168.0.188 'find /var/mobile/Media/Music/ [...]'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`sshpass -p YOUR_PASS_HERE ssh root@192.168.0.188  find /var/mobile/Media/Music/ -name "*.mp3" -exec ln -s {} /var/mobile/Media/Music/"All Songs" \;`

Cheers,
André Gondim
http://andregondim.eti.br

Comment: Providing password on the command line is not very secure. It's much better to use the public key authentication in such cases.