# How execute specific command from shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, scripts

I have below `shell` script, in which i am login into the particular machine, now i have to execute one command after login in , this command will start/stop/status of particular process.

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    spawn ssh root@hostname
    expect "Password:"
    send "password123\r"
    interact  # here it is successfully login into machine, 
    sleep 2
    /sbin/service heartbeat status # I want to execute this command
```

how I can do it ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine Two Commands In a Script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31233/combine-two-commands-in-a-script)

Comment: So, what is the problem? What you show should work. Is it failing somehow? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
ssh user@hostname "command"
```

This will open a ssh connection and run the command. You will be prompted for a password, if necessary.

If you want to do this automatically (don't want to enter your password everytime), you should enable a login with a ssh-pub-key.

Comment: @BhushanPatil then you should click the grey checkmark to accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Once the interactive `ssh` instance is spawned it takes over the current `bash` instance, and the following commands are not executed until it has finished its execution.

```
user@user-X550CL ~ % ssh user@localhost; echo string
user@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-15-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Tue Sep 15 09:10:01 2015 from localhost
user@user-X550CL ~ % exit
Connection to localhost closed.
string
```

There are multiple ways to solve this;

1. Pass the command(s) as an argument: `spawn ssh root@hostname /sbin/service heartbeat status`

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ssh user@localhost echo command1
user@localhost's password: 
command1
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ssh user@localhost 'echo command1; echo command2; echo command3'
user@localhost's password: 
command1
command2
command3
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp %
```

2. Group the command(s) into another script and pass the script using `stdin` redirection:

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ssh user@localhost <script.sh 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-15-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

command1
command2
command3
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp %
```

Comment: Thnaks KOS it solved my problem..!!

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!